# Closing Hamburger menu in React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i'm trying to close the hamburger menu onClick with react, but so far have no results :( Read a lot of similar questions here, but everyone html is different and none of the answers worked for me :( Here's the code, i know it should be done with with useState, but how can i do it ? It's the first condition, the second is just a search input for the start page

```
return (
        <>
            {city ?
                <nav>
                    <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" />
                    <div className="nav-input">
                        <form method='POST' type="text" className='form' onSubmit={searchLocation}>
                            <input className="form-input" name='city' placeholder='Enter your location ...' />
                            <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                                <img src={search} />
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <ul className="links">
                        <li><NavLink to="/now" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Now</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/hourly" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Hourly</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/daily" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Daily</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                    <label  htmlFor="nav-toggle" className="icon-burger">
                        <div className="line"></div>
                        <div className="line"></div>
                        <div className="line"></div>
                    </label>
                    {city ?
                        <div className='city-name'>
                            <p>weather at: </p>
                            <h4>{city}</h4>
                        </div>
                        : null}
                </nav>
                :
                <>
                    <div className='nav-start-page'>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Get Your Forecast</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Link className='location-link' to="/location">
                                <img src={location} />
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <form method='POST' type="text" onSubmit={searchLocation}>
                                <input className="form-input" name='city' placeholder='Enter your location ...' />
                                <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                                    <img src={search} />
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            }
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click event on hamburger menu and set menu list hidden by default from css
i.e; `visiblity: hidden`. And on menu click function get menu list div by id from js and set their css `visiblity: visible`

Answer (score 0):

Use **useState** and a callback function to toggle the hamburger menu onClick.

Try this:

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

return (
        <>
            {city ?
                <nav>
                    <input id="nav-toggle" type="checkbox" onClick={() => setIsOpen(!isOpen)} />
                    <div className="nav-input">
                        <form method='POST' type="text" className='form' onSubmit={searchLocation}>
                            <input className="form-input" name='city' placeholder='Enter your location ...' />
                            <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                                <img src={search} />
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    {isOpen && <ul className="links">
                        <li><NavLink to="/now" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Now</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/hourly" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Hourly</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/daily" style={({ isActive }) =>
                            isActive ? active : undefined
                        }>Daily</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>}
                    <label  htmlFor="nav-toggle" className="icon-burger">
                        <div className="line"></div>
                        <div className="line"></div>
                        <div className="line"></div>
                    </label>
                    {city ?
                        <div className='city-name'>
                            <p>weather at: </p>
                            <h4>{city}</h4>
                        </div>
                        : null}
                </nav>
                :
                <>
                    <div className='nav-start-page'>
                        <div>
                            <h3>Get Your Forecast</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Link className='location-link' to="/location">
                                <img src={location} />
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <form method='POST' type="text" onSubmit={searchLocation}>
                                <input className="form-input" name='city' placeholder='Enter your location ...' />
                                <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                                    <img src={search} />
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </>
            }
        </>
    );
};
```